# dimension of preimage of k dimensional subspace under epimorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

Let f be linear map from $V$ to $W$ and let f be epimorphism $(f(V)=W)$. Let $dimV=n$, $dimW=m$. Let E be $k$ dimensional subspace of $W$. Find $dimf^{-1}(E)$.

Comment: Hint: rank-nullity theorem with $f |_{f^{-1}(E)} : f^{-1}(E) \to E$.

Comment: I got the answer k+dimkerf but im not sure

Comment: you can actually rewrite the $\dim{\textrm{Ker} \; f}$ using rank-nullity again and the fact that $f$ is surjective.

Comment: how to do it???

Answer (score 1):

Using the rank-nullity theorem with $f |_{f^{-1}(E)} : f^{-1}(E) \to E$ gives $\dim{f^{-1}(E)} = \dim{\ker{f|_{f^{-1}(E)}}} + k$. OP implicitly made use of the fact that $\ker{f|_{f^{-1}(E)}} = \ker{f}$. Now with using rank-nullity with $f : V \to W$, we have $\dim{\ker{f}} = \dim{V} - \dim{W}$. Putting this together,
\begin{align}
\dim{f^{-1}(E)} = n - m + k.
\end{align}